# Can my app intercept SMSs if I am also responsible for sending those SMSs with a known specifc SMS short code?

Tags: ios

I know its not possible for iOS apps to intercept incoming SMSs in general.

However if my company is working in conjunction with a phone network operator and we have servers which generate SMSs targetted specifically at the iOS client using their gateways and have a specific SMS short code, then is it possible and legitimate for the iOS client to intercept those and only those SMSs orginating from the server?

Thanks

Comment: Why downgrade this question whoever did so? It is not about intercepting SMSs like all the other questions out there, read it again, it is about generating the SMSs from in within a network operator's gateway in conjunction with them (i.e. the likes of AT&T Verizon)and intercepting those. A bit different don't you think from all the other regular questions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. iOS apps *cannot* intercept SMS's, period. Your network operator needs to use a different mechanism to communicate with your app. [Apple Push Notifications](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ApplePushService/ApplePushService.html) are a good choice if you need to alert the user, as long as the limitations of APN are acceptable. If you need some solution that actually launches your app on-demand when the message is received, well, that doesn't exist.

Comment: So if a network operator has their own application which runs on the iOS which they sell, then they have no mechanisms available to them beyond what somebody developing iOS apps in their bedroom has?

Comment: @Mungbeans: To the best of my knowledge, that is correct.